# C++ For loop Beginner incorrect output

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, int

I started college this year doing a course in software development. I've just started doing loops in c++ and have been assigned a number of questions to solve. I have the code done for the first question but part of the output is not working correctly and I can't figure out why.

The problem is to read in the marks of 10 student in a test and then output the pecentage of student that received an honors mark (over 70)

Here is my code

```
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    int grade;
    int numfirstclass = 0;
    int percentfirstclass;


    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)// For loop to run 10 times to allow 10 grades to be entered
    {
        cout << "Enter your grade ";
        cin >> grade;

        if (grade >= 70)
            numfirstclass++;
    }


    cout << "The number of students with a first class honours degree is:" <<  numfirstclass;
    percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10) * 100;
    cout << endl << "The Percentage of students that recieved a first class degree is: " << percentfirstclass;



    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the output for percentfirstclass is always 0 and I can't figure out why.

Any explanation would be appreciated

I'm using visual studio 2013

Comment: `numfirstclass/10` is always 0 since `numfirstclass` is `int` with value < 10. Note that you're doing `int` calculations, change it to `double` and let us know if you still have problems.

Comment: You are forcing C++ to evaluate `numfirstclass/10` first, which will be `0` for every number below 10 (as these are integers). The multiplication by 100 comes too late. Remove the parentheses and put the `100` at the start. ...Or multiply by (100/10).

Comment: Thanks guys I changed it to double and its working now. Sorry for the noob mistake. I understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10(double)) * 100;
```

`numfirstclass / 10` will always evaluate to 0 (except when `numfirstclass` is 1) as it is an integer division and multiplying 100 and 0 is always 0.

Using the cast will make `numfirstclass / 10(double)` result in a number having a decimal part and then,it will be multiplied with 100 . This number will then be assigned to `percentfirstclass` and as `percentfirstclass` is an `int`,the decimal part will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that subexpression

```
(numfirstclass / 10)
```

of expression

```
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10) * 100;
```

is always equal to 0 because `numfirstclass` is always less than 10 except one case when numfirstclass is equal to 10.:) There is used the integer arithmetic.

You could either define `numfirstclass` as having type float (or double) or rewrite the statement as

```
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass * 100 ) / 10;
```

or to force the expression to be evaluated as a float number

```
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10.0) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

As cool guy told change the percentfirstclass to float or double, in your above code you are trying to divide an integer by 10 which is lesser than 10, so the program returns 0 as output 
i.e.

int c =1;
 int d = c/10;//gives 0 because integers cannit support decimals

if you use

float d = c/10;//you will get your required output

Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the type `double`.Write

```
double percentfirstclass;
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10.0) * 100;
```

instead

```
int percentfirstclass;
percentfirstclass = (numfirstclass / 10) * 100;
```